# My loop works, but I get 'Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection' when I try to use it on my folder of txt files

Tags: r, function, loops, lapply

I created a loop, but am having a lot of issues when I try to use that over the files that I need the loop to go on. I have tried a series of things, and I think this is the closest I have got to making it work. The only problem I am facing now is the very last line of code, when I use lapply - it says Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection.

Any help at all is appreciated! I am just starting out.

```
setwd<- ("C:/Users/k.ganeson/Desktop/accession_commitments")
    extract_info = function(file) {
    text <- readLines(("C:/Users/k.ganeson/Desktop/accession_commitments"))
clean_text <- as.data.frame(strsplit(text$text, '\\*' ), col.names = "text") %>% # split the text in different lines 

# clean text getting rid of special text characters, useless whitespaces etc
mutate(text = str_replace_all(text, "\n", " "),
       text = str_replace_all(text, "- ", ""), 
       text = str_replace_all(text,"^\\s", "")) %>% 

# take out lines where there is nothing
filter(!text == " ") %>% 

## Now we want to separate in two columns the type of commitments and the actual commitments paragraphs
# First we copy the commitments' paragraph in another column
mutate(paragraphs = ifelse(grepl("^[[:digit:]]", text) == T, text, NA)) %>% 

# We rename column text as category to avoid confusion 
rename(category = text) %>% 

# In category column we don't need the paragraphs anymore so we put NAs instead
# and then fill the column with the categories
mutate(category = ifelse(grepl("^[[:digit:]]", category) == T, NA, category)) %>% 
fill(category) %>% 

# Now we can get rid of all lines with NAs in the paragraphs column as they are useless
filter(!is.na(paragraphs)) %>% 

# Now separate all the different commitments' paragraph in different rows
mutate(paragraphs = strsplit(paragraphs, '^[[:digit:]]{1,3}\\.|\\t\\s[[:digit:]]{1,3}\\.')) %>% 
unnest(paragraphs) %>% 

# Make sure to also separate the last bit of javascript (starting from Download as PDF etc) so that
# it does not show up as one of the commitments 
mutate(paragraphs = strsplit(paragraphs, 'Download as PDF')) %>%
unnest(paragraphs) %>% 

## last cleaning 
mutate(paragraphs = str_replace_all(paragraphs, "\t", "")) %>% # get rid of text special characters as we don't need them anymore
mutate(paragraphs = ifelse(grepl("javascript", paragraphs), "", paragraphs)) %>% #  get rid of any potential remaning java script code that is useless 
mutate(paragraphs = str_replace_all(paragraphs, "^\\s+", "")) %>% # sometimes we have empty cells in paragraphs with one or more whitespace, replace all of them by ""
filter(!paragraphs == "") # now get rid of all empty lines}
#list of all files to go through the loop
my_files = list.files(path = "C:/Users/k.ganeson/Desktop/accession_commitments",
                  pattern = "txt")

my_files #Apply function to these files
    results = lapply(my_files, extract_info)
```

Comment: Try with `list.files(..., full.names = TRUE)`. By default `list.files` will only return a list of filenames. Hence when using lapply it will look for the files in the working directory. Setting full.names=TRUE will include the path to your files.

Comment: Wow, this worked! Can't believe adding something like this makes all the difference. Thank you so much!